# Работа с изображением через System.Windows.Media VS System.Drawing

Tags: c#, .net, графика

Подскажите, каким пространством при работе с изображениями лучше пользоваться в новых проектах?

Вроде, если смотреть поверхностно, то функциональность схожая.

Есть ли какая-то разница в производительности или за кулисами это 2 обертки над старым добрым GDI+?

Пока я столкнулся с тем, что WPF может отображать картинки типа `ImageSource`, а `Image` из пространства `System.Drawing` нужно дополнительно кастовать.

И вот собственно вопрос, а имеет смысл везде использовать `System.Windows.Media` или все зависит от конечных задач и если неизвестно, с каким GUI будет работать конечная библиотека, то лучше возвращать `Image` из `Drawing`, а сам пользователь будет его приводить к нужному типу сам?

Вроде, как `System.Drawing` лежит, как отдельная независимая библиотека, в то время, как `System.Windows.Media` лежит в либе WPF-фреймворка. Получается, что все таки `Drawing` нужно использовать повсеместно?

Перечисления кстати, тоже дублируются между пространствами. Например, перечисление цветов.

Comment: А что планируется делать с изображениями? Мне кажется исходить нужно из этого. Масштабирование и искажения геометрии без изменения исходных пикселей вероятнее всего DirectX под капотом System.Windows.Media сделает лучше и быстрее, а вот за создание изображений ни чего сказать не могу, пока только GDI для этого использовал.

Answer (score 3):

Если неизвестно с каким GUI работать и говорить про новые проекты, то это значит есть смысл делать проект на .NET Core и делать ставку только на кроссплатформенные библиотеки. Когда использовал кроссплатформенный подход лучше всего себя как раз и зарекомендовал `System.Drawing`. Для его использования нужно добавить NuGet-пакет `System.Drawing.Common`.

Я пробовал использовать различные альтернативы [отсюда](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/), но либо не были кроссплатформенными, содержали баги или их было не очень просто добавить проект без кучи дополнительных шагов.

По поводу возрата конкретного типа: я не совсем согласен насчёт использования типа `System.Drawing.Image` для конечного пользователя, я бы лучше возвращал массив байт или если это Rest API, то возвращал бы строку Base64. В целом, мне кажется достаточно возвращать любой тип, который совместим с .NET Standard.